# Only able to change UIBarButton title when using a hard-coded string

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a pretty common scenario. A tree of unknown depth based on data, so I have a navigation controller with a `tableView` controller as the root controller. Every time I need to go deeper, I create a new `tableview` controller, populate it with data based on the previous selection, and push the new `tableview` controller onto the navigation controller stack:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cellText = cell?.textLabel?.text 
    let bcti = CustomDataClass(querystring: cellText!)

    if(bcti.getStatus() == "Drill")
    {
        let bctvc = CustomTableViewControllerClass(tableinfo: bcti)

        //Note: self in this instance is my custom UITableViewController class
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: cellText, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bctvc, animated: true)

    }
```

This works fine, a new `tableview` controller is created based on the selected cell from the previous controller, pushing it on the navigation stack works fine as well. The weird thing is I can't seem to get the back bar item to display the selected value from the previous controller.
If I use the `cellText` variable containing the text of the previously selected cell (as shown in the code above) to assign the `UIBarButton` `title`, it seems to ignore that and default to having 'Back' as the title anyway. 
The `cellText` variable clearly has the correct value in it, I verified with `NSLog` statements, and also even tried conditionally unwrapping it to be 100% sure it has a value at run-time. It's being used to progress in the first place, so I think we can hopefully rule out an optional `nil` issue.

What's really strange to me though is that hard-coding a string into the title works just fine. So for instance if I replace:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: cellText, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

with:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Bananas", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

It correctly displays Bananas instead of Back. I can also declare a variable and hard code that with a different value and it works fine. I.E:

```
let tempvar = "Bananas!"
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: tempvar, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

It seems to only be when I try to access the text associated with the cell that it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? Something else that might be worth noting is that I'm using a Storyboard to set up my initial navigation controller & tableview controller, I'm only creating the new instances of the `tableview` controller programmatically.

Comment: Have you examined the cellText variable to see what the value actually is?

Comment: @PeterSegerblom Yes, as I mentioned I checked it both with an NSLog displaying the unwrapped value, and I've also tried setting the title with a conditional unwrap (I.E: if let test = cellText{self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:test,...}

Comment: Check what [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html) of `backBarButtonItem` says. The cell text might simply be too long.

Comment: @A-Live I forgot to mention this, but I've also tried hard-coding the exact value of what the cell text is. And hard-coding the same value works fine, so I don't believe it's an issue with the length of the string in this instance.

Comment: Instead of trying to hardcode the same values, try to change the datasource so that it has very short text values and see if it works. E.g. the cells might be displaying the first line of the multiline text now and you might have hardcoded a copy of only the first (the only visible) line. Hardcode is bad, even for tests.

Comment: @A-Live Crap, it looks like you're right... Putting in shorter values in the data source worked for some reason. If you want to post that as the answer I'll choose it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you find any additional information, please add it somewhere at the comments or as your own answer for the other users to be able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what the documentation of backBarButtonItem says. The cell text might simply be too long.

Instead of trying to hardcode the same values, try to change the datasource so that it has very short text values and see if it works. E.g. the cells might be displaying the first line of the multiline text now and you might have hardcoded a copy of only the first (the only visible) line. Hardcode is bad, even for tests.